# .Determine the pass percentage given the following conditions?

Tags: percentages

[image: Determine the pass percentage]

**MyApproach**

I want to ask is this question incorrect because the data given to us says $80$% of the students passed in maths and how $29$% of the students failed in both?

Comment: You are right, the question seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be correct. Maybe your teacher failed in mathematics?

A necessary condition for the well-posedness of this question is

$P(\text{passing maths}) + P(\text{failing math and english}) \leq 100\%$